# Videojs is not working well in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, iphone, wordpress, mobile, video.js

An issue with playing the video on iOS devices (tested on iPhone 7 and 5s iOS 11)

There are two play buttons in https://www.biznessapps.com/reseller/ and each of them shows full screen video when clicked.

It works fine on desktop browsers, but when I click Close button (cross-mark) on mobile devices, it works odd and after second clicking the screen is black and just audio is played.

I'm using the latest version of Video.js:  (v6.4.0)
http://videojs.com/

Steps:

1. Open https://www.biznessapps.com/progressive-web-apps/ in Safari.
2. Tap on "Watch the video".
3. Play the video and tap close button "X".

Actual result: video does not close and after reopening the video plays with a black screen.

Video: https://www.screencast.com/t/zEqRgLuW
Note: This is happening on other pages as well.

Other pages:

https://www.biznessapps.com/reseller/

https://www.biznessapps.com/progressive-web-apps/

Code for reference:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.4.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://www.biznessapps.com/frontendwp/wp-content/themes/biznessapps-theme/style-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.4.0/video.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="page page-id-9888 page-template page-template-template-extra-full-width page-template-template-extra-full-width-php logged-in admin-bar is-page-reseller wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.12 vc_responsive mpc-loaded customize-support">

    <div data-type="reseller" class="video-content">
        <div class="video-wrap">
            <div class="video-mask"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- FULL WIDTH VIDEO -->
    <!-- Reseller Hero -->
    <div data-name="reseller_hero" class="full-width-video" id="full_width_video_reseller_hero">
        <div class="video-close"></div>
        <video id="video_full_reseller_hero" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
            <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/237113285.hd.mp4?s=e562af1d980dbd405f142c7f9ca72346e8892386&profile_id=174" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>

    <!-- Reseller Team -->
    <div data-name="reseller_team" class="full-width-video" id="full_width_video_reseller_team">
        <div class="video-close"></div>
        <video id="video_full_reseller_team" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
            <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/207374075.hd.mp4?s=250498588d84bc39b88e39cb101177684defdf56&profile_id=175" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>


    <div class="white-play-video">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn-play-video" data-video-id="reseller_hero"><span class="play-circle"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span><span class="lbl">Watch the video</span></a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var fullWidthPlayers = {};

        $(".btn-play-video").each(function() {
            var $btn = $(this),
                videoId = $btn.data('videoId') || framework.fwVideo.videoType;

            var $videoContainer = $('#full_width_video_' + videoId);
            if ($videoContainer.length == 0) {
              console.error('[framework.fwVideo.init] Video container is not found for ' + videoId + '. Skipping');
              return true;
            }

            var $videoFull = $videoContainer.find('video');

            fullWidthPlayers[videoId] = videojs($videoFull[0], {
                techOrder: ['html5'],
                controls: true,
                autoplay: false,
                preload: 'auto',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            });
        })
    </script>

</body>
```

Please note that actual JS in the current pages with this issue does not include video.js from CDN directly and it creates bundle.js with `require()` functions by Gulpfile.